# Observer not notified when value changed to false

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I am trying out Angular and rxjs (6.0) and got stuck in a scenario.

Here it goes,

This is my sample codebase: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kxqj8d?file=app%2Finput-overview-example.ts

```
var service = {
  isUserSignedIn: null
};
var myObservable$ = new BehaviorSubject(service);

setInterval(function() {
  debugger;
  service.isUserSignedIn = !service.isUserSignedIn;
  service = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(service));
  console.log("--------------------------------------------")
  console.log("Value update to : " + service.isUserSignedIn)
  myObservable$.next(service);


}.bind(this), 5000);


myObservable$
  .pipe(
  filter((curr) => curr.isUserSignedIn != null),
  distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => {
    debugger;
    console.log("Value during comparison prev: " + prev.isUserSignedIn + " curr: " + curr.isUserSignedIn)
    return prev.isUserSignedIn === curr.isUserSignedIn;
  }))
  .subscribe(value => {
    console.log("Got Notified! New Value: " + value.isUserSignedIn);
  })
```

Here's the console logs:

[image: Observer not notified in rxjs angular]

Inside the "distinctUntilChanged" operator, both the values prev and curr are the same when the flag "service.isUserSignedIn" is set to false. But works correctly when the same flag is set to true!

Because of this, observer is not being notified!

I spent last two days trying to figure out, but couldn't find what's wrong.

Can you guys please help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the result of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(service))` to a new variable and pass that to `next`. If you don't do that, then you are overwriting the previous value of service, effectively defeating the purpose of creating a copy with JSON parse/stringify.

[Updated Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kxqj8d-6yergu?file=app/input-overview-example.ts)

#### Side note

Consider this more concise piece of code:

```
interval(5000).pipe(
  map(() => {
    service.isUserSignedIn = !service.isUserSignedIn;
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(service));
  }),
  distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => {
    console.log(prev.isUserSignedIn, curr.isUserSignedIn)
    return prev.isUserSignedIn === curr.isUserSignedIn;
  })
)
.subscribe(value => {
  console.log(`Result: ${value.isUserSignedIn}`)
});
```

Comment: Thank you Sam. Just curious, if this is the correction solution, then how can we proceed if the "service" is an object containing other objects and so on. I mean, will it still work if the object is deep?

Comment: Vinay, I updated my side note example to use JSON parse/stringify like you had it. You are correct that [`Object.assign` only creates a shallow copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone)